# .Net Core 3.1 - Incorrect matching of endpoint template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

It looks like the endpoint pattern is matching greedy instead of going down to the next best match. I can also see that it totally ignores the attribute routing specified on the controller action. Please see the code snippets below.

**startup.cs**

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "one",
                    pattern: "{CompanyType}/{CompanyId}/{controller}/{EmployeeUuid:Guid}/{action}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "two",
                    pattern: "{CompanyType}/{CompanyId}/{controller}/{action}");
            });
```

**TestController.cs**

```
namespace RoutingTest.Controllers
{
    [Route("{CompanyType}/{CompanyId}/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public TestController() { }

        [HttpGet("{EmployeeId:Guid}/[action]", Name = "Employee_Open")]
        public IActionResult OpenEmployee(bool edit = false, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
            return View("Employee");
        }
        [HttpPost("[action]", Name = "Employee_Save")]
        public IActionResult SaveEmployee(Employee model, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("Employee_Open", new { CompanyType = "hr", CompanyId = "776cfe52-d39a-411d-88f3-c97e6895eb63", EmployeeId = Guid.NewGuid() });
        }
    }
}
```

**Currently  loaded page's URL.**

`http://localhost:5000/hr/776cfe52-d39a-411d-88f3-c97e6895eb63/Test/1d3843a4-7409-4f19-affc-de9aa47f48db/OpenEmployee?edit=true`

**Employee.cshtml**

```
@model Employee

<form asp-controller="test" asp-action="saveemployee">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        <div>
            <button asp-controller="test" asp-action="saveemployee" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Save
            </button>
            <a asp-route="Employee_Open" asp-route-employeeid="@Model.uuid" asp-route-edit="true">
                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Generate HTML of the save button**

`<button type="submit" formaction="/hr/776cfe52-d39a-411d-88f3-c97e6895eb63/test/1d3843a4-7409-4f19-affc-de9aa47f48db/saveemployee">Save</button>`

As you can see the generated **formaction** url inserted the employee id before the action name though it is not there as a token in the specified attribute routing. This happens because it matches the first endpoint defined in the startup class instead of going down to the second endpoint. Is this a bug in .net core 3.1? Or is there something wrong in my code or approach?

Comment: Why is one a GET and the other a PUT?  The GET/PUT is the body of the request/response and can be optional.  A controller can be either at a client or server and following sequence occurs 1) Client sends request using PUT 2) Server receives request with GET 3) Server processes the request 4) Server sends response with PUT 5) Client receives response with GET.

Comment: I didn't follow. There is a GET method for open action and the save action is POST. Why you think the POST request will be received by Server as GET?

Comment: A client sends the request and receives the response.  A client cannot receive the request nor send the response.  It make no sense to have options where one is a GET and the other is a PUT.  Likewise the server is the reverse from the client.

Comment: @jdweng - GET/POST annotations look totally fine and match the request method https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: I totally don't get what you mean. Can you be specific what needs to be corrected here

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Thanks for confirming.

Comment: The link says exactly what I said.  You are wrong. "GET should only retrieve data". "The POST method is used to submit"  Is the code that is not working in a client or server?  You need a separate controller for the client code and the server code.  One controller cannot be both a client and server.  So putting a GET and a POST in the same method is wrong.  If the code is in a client's request both the  Employee_Open and Employee_Save are sending a request with a body and both should be POST.  If the code is for a response than both should be GET.  Same applies if controller is in server.

Comment: as far as I know the actions in a controller can be of any HTTP Verbs in .Net

Comment: @jdweng - that really makes no sense to me. Controllers are always on the server side and a client (web browser) sends requests to those controllers. It makes absolutely no difference if you place two methods on the same controller or on two controllers (except of routing) and everywhere they can be mapped to any http method.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen :  Absolutely wrong.  Controllers can process responses just as well as requests.  Clients can use HttpRequest which is equivalent to a browser without the graphic controls.  The format of a request and response are both http and have http headers and bodies.

Comment: To answer your original question.  You controller looks like it is at the client because it is doing the SAVE which is the POST.  A server the GET would be done before the PUT.  You are not getting any match response at the client because the GET is not being executed.  Which means either the connection never completed, the server did not send a response, or the response did not match the IActionResult.

Comment: @jdweng - knowing that this is the wrong place to discuss this, but really - controllers always handle requests from a client. Input = HttpRequest and output = HttpResponse. If you want to initiate the request, use HttpClient which has nothing to do with controllers. http requests have different methods and a controller can handle all of them. This includes the fact that there can be multiple methods for the same path but for different http methods. Btw. this is a very common pattern where show page = GET request and submit form = POST request.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen : Why can't they be used in client?  It is the same structure.

Comment: @jdweng - that depends on how we define 'client'. What we know here: It's asp.net and running on a server. We see the actions return html, so the 'client' is the web browser. A browser sends requests to controller actions on the server and the actions return responses (simplified). These requests have a http method defined in the header. This method can be GET,POST,PUT,... The routing maps requests to actions by path and method. There's simply nothing indicating that we're seeing something we would call 'client' here and when the browser sends a POST request, we'll receive a POST request here.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen : You are making assumptions that are wrong.  It looks like OPs is using client to test a server.  With a test case you want it to be automatic and may want the response to be automatically verified instead of going to a browser.